# Calculate unit rate and quantity using Sql Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am giving query and table column name with datatype.

```
Column name       Data Type
iBasicRate        Decimal             
iTaxesAndLevies   Decimal
vsUnitRate        nchar
iAmount          Deciaml 
vsQuantity       Deciaml
```

**First Query Find Unit Rate**

**Formula is**  `Unit Rate=Basic Rate + Taxes`

```
CASE tBOQ.iBOQLineItemType WHEN '3' THEN Convert(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL,tBOQ.iBasicRate)) + Convert(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL,tBOQ.iTaxesAndLevies))
          WHEN '5' THEN Convert(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL,tBOQ.iBasicRate)) + Convert(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DECIMAL,tBOQ.iTaxesAndLevies))      
          ELSE '---'       
          END    as vsUnitRate,
```

In this query this is not giving add (addition of amount ) it is just append the next amount.
Example :

```
Basic rate     Tax      Unit rate(Basic rate+tax)
4500.00        225.00   4500225 (Show like this)
```

**And Second Query Find Amount**

**Formula is**  `Unit Rate*Quantity=Amount`

```
CASE tBOQ.iBOQLineItemType WHEN '3' THEN CONVERT(varchar,tBOQ.iAmount)  
          WHEN '5' THEN CONVERT(varchar,tBOQ.iAmount)          
          ELSE '---'         
          END    as iAmount ,
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: why are using `convert` ? jus try- select case when itemtype=3 then basicrate+taxe end as xxx1, case when itemtype=5 then .... end as xxx2

Comment: why is your unitrate is nchar type? change it to decimal and remove convert.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?:

```
CASE WHEN tBOQ.iBOQLineItemType in ('3', '5') THEN tBOQ.iBasicRate + 
                                                   tBOQ.iTaxesAndLevies
          ELSE 0       
          END  as vsUnitRate,

CASE WHEN tBOQ.iBOQLineItemType in ('3', '5') THEN (tBOQ.iBasicRate + 
                                                    tBOQ.iTaxesAndLevies) * 
                                                    tBOQ.vsQuantity       
          ELSE 0         
          END   as iAmount ,
```